# need Advice on ID3 implementation and Datatype to be used

Tags: python, machine-learning

Need advice:
I am implementing ID3 algorithm in Machine Learning. I am using dictionary to read the training file and store into. But as I am going forward I am understanding that in dictionary v dont have fixed places for each key,value pair as in list or array. Now I might have problem in getting the position of the final attribute and passing it dynamically to other functions. Should i change to some other data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2.7 and 3.x have an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) that could be an option for you.